# importing hashlib error after mac os updated

Tags: python, macos-sierra, hashlib

After upgrading my `mac os` from `Captain to Sierra`, I am getting following error while importing hashlib.

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute
>   'openssl_md_meth_names'

The library was getting successfully imported in the `Captain` version.
But after the upgrade its stopped all of a sudden.
Python version being used is `2.7.8`.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Add the openssl and hashlib versions...

Comment: Being new to this, can you please tell how to get the version.